# how to solve this error with django and ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

i just want to pass the selected id of the option via ajax request to django 2.1 but it always returns me some errors . i am new to django and web development so please help to solve this issue
js code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
document.querySelector('#mainoption').onchange=()=>{
  const id=document.querySelector('#mainoption').value;
  const request=new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.open('GET','submain');
  request.send(id);
  alert("selected  "+id);
}
```

});

django code

```
def submain(request):
subid = request.GET.get('id')

print(subid)
return HttpResponse(subid)
```

[image: django]

[image: javascript]

[image: frontend]

the out put of subid is none why this happen

Comment: Please post your code snippet as text, not as an image.

Comment: Check network tab in dev tool. And check what is the response of `/submain` api.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529518/django-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django "view didn't return an HttpResponse object."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529518/django-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object)

Comment: It seems there is problem with your python script. May be not importing the required files. POST YOUR CODE NOT IMAGE.

Comment: i added the code
actually i want to learn ajax django integration but i cant found any doc or tutorials for that please help me with this i want to learn how to implement ajax in django

Comment: your code needs indentation fix

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the submain view is not returning an HttpResponse object. You need to return an HttpResponse object.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def submain(request):
    subid = request.POST.get('id')
    return HttpResponse(subid)
```

Change your AJAX request to

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
document.querySelector('#mainoption').onchange=()=>{
  const id=document.querySelector('#mainoption').value;
  const request=new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.open('POST','submain');
  request.send("id="+id);
  alert("selected  "+id);
}
```

Comment: yeah but the content inside subid is none

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest.send() method ignores the body parameter if the request method is GET: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send. GET requests URL encode information, e.g. "http://example.com/submain/?id=1". You probably want to make a POST request to transmit data to the server

Comment: so what is the proper method to access the subid in django

Comment: Send your AJAX request like the POST example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST
Then in your Django view, you can access it with ```request.POST.get('id')```

Comment: This tutorial may be helpful: https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

For more complicated Django APIs, I highly recommend checking out Django REST Framework: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: You're welcome! If this helped, please accept my answer - I'm new and trying to earn some reputation. Thank you.